# Hosting multiple repositories, each with differing access control

Tags: security, apache-2.2, mercurial, access-control-list

We will need to host a series of Mercurial repositories.  For security, we will use SSL encryption in Apache and htpasswd access (required).  I tested out a single repository and used `hgwebdir.cgi` and used the `hgweb.config` to define the repository path and the `allow_push` and `deny_push` directives, but this test setup has only lead to more questions/problems:

I don't see any way to make a different allow/deny push group for each separate repository? ore importantly, I see no method to `allow_pull` `deny_pull` — which is quite important as each repository has a different set of users who should be allowed to read or write.  We'd like to keep one `htpasswd` file for all users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are likely missing is that it is perfectly allowable to create a `.hg/hgrc` file inside each repository, and those files can contain `allow_push` and `allow_read` entries.

Comment: In addition, you also have deny_push and deny_read. So you can choose a whilelist/blacklist/mix approach.

Answer (score 1):

[Mercurial-server](http://www.lshift.net/mercurial-server.html) is a great way to host many Mercurial repos with different access requirements per repos.

If you decide this is not for you then you should take a look at the **ACL** extension to Mercurial.

Comment: Please note that mercurial-server is a *third-party* tool. It is not needed for maintaining a Mercurial server, though it can be a convenient way to do so when using SSH for access control.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to `allow_pull` or `deny_pull` is to set up httpd authentication using the htpasswd file.  You could use any of the `mod_auth` mechanisms here to allow each user to pull or push.

You might also look into using the SSH transport for hosting as that will give you a finer grained control over access, at the cost of a slightly more complicated setup.

More info can be found [in the Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories).